# Nginx In Bitbucket pipelines

Tags: docker, nginx, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to run a web server with Bitbucket Pipelines.

This is my bitbucket-pipelines.yml so far:

```
image: php:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - composer install
          - vendor/bin/behat --colors --format=pretty --out=std
        services:
          - selenium
          - nginx

definitions:
  services:
    selenium:
      hostname: selenium
      image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
    nginx:
      image: nginx
```

Now if I go to http://localhost I can see the default Nginx page.

How can I serve some files in the repository instead of that?
Is it possible to copy files to the Nginx container?

Comment: Trying achieve the same with Apache2. Can you see the files in the `/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build` within your image? I think this is the directory Bitbucket puts the repo files in.

Comment: Yes, my files are there. I want to somehow copy those files to the Nginx container.

Comment: Instead of `services` you can use `docker` natively. Then you can mount that directory to the container itself as a part of `docker run` command.

Comment: I am actually using `docker-compose` command to build services and link between them, and mount the files providing this to `volumes`: `- $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR:/your/location`

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like mounting files isn't possible in the bitbucket services without getting all meta and using custom Docker-in-Docker images, so I ended up ditching the nginx service. However I successfully managed to run the PHP built in webserver!

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:80 public/index.php &
```

The `-S` option starts the built in dev server, and `public/index.php` is my app's entrypoint. The `&` pushes the process into the background. It only seems to work with the `127.0.0.1` IP, if you try a custom host it won't work.

Here's my full pipeline config:

```
image:
  name: php:8.1-fpm
  username: $DH_USER
  password: $DH_PASS

definitions:
  services:
    db:
      image: mariadb:10.2
      variables:
        MARIADB_DATABASE: MY_TEST_DB
        MARIADB_USER: root
        MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
    chrome:
      image: selenium/standalone-chrome
      ports:
        - 4444
        - 5900


pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    '**':
      - step:
          services:
            - db
            - chrome
          name: Installing Composer and running Unit Tests...
          script:
            - if [[ "${BITBUCKET_PR_DESTINATION_BRANCH}" != "develop" ]] && [[ "${BITBUCKET_PR_DESTINATION_BRANCH}" != "release/"* ]]; then printf "Skipping Tests for this target (${BITBUCKET_PR_DESTINATION_BRANCH})"; exit; fi
            - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
            - composer install --no-scripts
            - vendor/bin/grumphp git:pre-commit
            - cp config/autoload/data.test.php.dist config/autoload/data.test.php
            - php bin/console orm:schema-tool:create
            - php bin/console fixtures:load
            - php -S 127.0.0.1:80 public/index.php &
            - vendor/bin/codecept run

  branches:
    develop:
      - step:
          services:
            - db
          name: Installing Composer and running Unit Tests...
          script:
            - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
            - composer install --no-scripts
            - vendor/bin/grumphp git:pre-commit
            - cp config/autoload/data.test.php.dist config/autoload/data.test.php
            - php bin/console orm:schema-tool:update --force --complete
            - php bin/console fixtures:load
            - php -S 127.0.0.1:80 public/index.php &
            - vendor/bin/codecept run unit
```